# Nginx, subdomains and ssl

Tags: nginx, ssl, subdomain

I have a problem with nginx production server.

The problem is that nginx reads default.conf, and apply ssl_protocols directive to all subdomains. I want different subdomains to  have different security levels.

I already tested various configurations and discovered that the first configuration that nginx sees is the one that i would apply to all the other configurations.

> Nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

server_tokens off;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

> Default.conf

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

server_tokens off;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginxssl/ssl2/server.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginxssl/ssl2/key.pem;

#ssl_certificate /etc/nginxssl/muststaple/0001_chain.pem;
#ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginxssl/muststaple/private.key;  

ssl_certificate /etc/nginxssl/ssl.inuse/bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginxssl/ssl.inuse/key.pem;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dh8192.pem;
ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginxssl/tchain.pem;
resolver 8.8.8.8;
resolver_timeout 15s;

add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0; no-cache";
add_header Public-Key-Pins 'pin-sha256="G9VXPN07a9AeYSrdmCEQE/rMnb6gHPrPRsKwIyT+650="; pin-sha256="1wwt81mSLZfNaP9pzX3ii3MQSr93tI2G1sVvyxphs6U="; pin-sha256="Fbs+o+IxVNTHBpjNQYfX/TBnxPC+OWLYxQLEtqkrAfM="; pin-sha256="5C8kvU039KouVrl52D0eZSGf4Onjo4Khs8tmyTlV3nU="; pin-sha256="So2JKPjxjOGRXtH0ZlJOOS22/2/iiSIff0HfEtWlJjU="; report-uri="https://example.report-uri.io/r/default/hpkp/enforce"; max-age=5184000; preload';
    add_header Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only 'pin-sha256="G9VXPN07a9AeYSrdmCEQE/rMnb6gHPrPRsKwIyT+650="; pin-sha256="1wwt81mSLZfNaP9pzX3ii3MQSr93tI2G1sVvyxphs6U="; pin-sha256="Fbs+o+IxVNTHBpjNQYfX/TBnxPC+OWLYxQLEtqkrAfM="; pin-sha256="5C8kvU039KouVrl52D0eZSGf4Onjo4Khs8tmyTlV3nU="; pin-sha256="So2JKPjxjOGRXtH0ZlJOOS22/2/iiSIff0HfEtWlJjU="; report-uri="https://example.report-uri.io/r/default/hpkp/reportOnly"; max-age=5184000; preload';
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' cdnjs.cloudflare.com code.jquery.com scotthelme.disqus.com a.disquscdn.com www.google-analytics.com go.disqus.com platform.twitter.com cdn.syndication.twimg.com; style-src 'self' a.disquscdn.com fonts.googleapis.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com platform.twitter.com; img-src 'self' data: www.gravatar.com www.google-analytics.com links.services.disqus.com referrer.disqus.com a.disquscdn.com cdn.syndication.twimg.com syndication.twitter.com pbs.twimg.com platform.twitter.com abs.twimg.com; referrer 'strict-origin'; child-src fusiontables.googleusercontent.com fusiontables.google.com www.google.com disqus.com www.youtube.com syndication.twitter.com platform.twitter.com; frame-src fusiontables.googleusercontent.com fusiontables.google.com www.google.com disqus.com www.youtube.com syndication.twitter.com platform.twitter.com; connect-src 'self' links.services.disqus.com; font-src 'self' cdnjs.cloudflare.com fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com; form-action 'self'; upgrade-insecure-requests; report-uri https://alessandroz.report-uri.io/r/default/csp/enforce";
add_header Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "default-src 'none'; script-src 'nonce-qdHVoB7kz1TPDbuu2FhkGmUbYTCh3tzY' 'strict-dynamic'; style-src 'nonce-qdHVoB7kz1TPDbuu2FhkGmUbYTCh3tzY' a.disquscdn.com; child-src fusiontables.googleusercontent.com fusiontables.google.com www.google.com disqus.com www.youtube.com syndication.twitter.com platform.twitter.com; frame-src fusiontables.googleusercontent.com fusiontables.google.com www.google.com disqus.com www.youtube.com syndication.twitter.com platform.twitter.com; connect-src 'self' links.services.disqus.com; font-src cdnjs.cloudflare.com fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com; form-action 'self'; report-uri https://alessandroz.report-uri.io/r/default/csp/reportOnly";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header Referrer-Policy strict-origin;   
add_header Accept-Ranges bytes;

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_min_length 256;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;

root /usr/share/nginx/www;

location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
location = /robots.txt {log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }   

index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name example.com;



location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
    }

#location ~ (\.cgi|\.py|\.sh|\.pl|\.lua)$ {
    #gzip off;
#root /usr/share/nginx/tripwire;
    #autoindex on;
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    #nclude /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    #fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /usr/share/nginx/tripwire;
    #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/tripwire$fastcgi_script_name;
#}

location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
     }
    }

    }

    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    gzip off;
    }
```

> Sample NOT Default Configuration

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;

server_tokens off;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginxssl/hipaanist/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginxssl/hipaanist/privkey.pem;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dh8192.pem;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
#ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginxssl/tchain.pem;
resolver 8.8.8.8;
resolver_timeout 15s;

add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0; no-cache";
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' cdnjs.cloudflare.com code.jquery.com scotthelme.disqus.com a.disquscdn.com www.google-analytics.com go.disqus.com platform.twitter.com cdn.syndication.twimg.com; style-src 'self' a.disquscdn.com fonts.googleapis.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com platform.twitter.com; img-src 'self' data: www.gravatar.com www.google-analytics.com links.services.disqus.com referrer.disqus.com a.disquscdn.com cdn.syndication.twimg.com syndication.twitter.com pbs.twimg.com platform.twitter.com abs.twimg.com; referrer 'strict-origin'; child-src fusiontables.googleusercontent.com fusiontables.google.com www.google.com disqus.com www.youtube.com syndication.twitter.com platform.twitter.com; frame-src fusiontables.googleusercontent.com fusiontables.google.com www.google.com disqus.com www.youtube.com syndication.twitter.com platform.twitter.com; connect-src 'self' links.services.disqus.com; font-src 'self' cdnjs.cloudflare.com fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com; form-action 'self'; upgrade-insecure-requests; report-uri https://alessandroz.report-uri.io/r/default/csp/enforce";
add_header Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "default-src 'none'; script-src 'nonce-qdHVoB7kz1TPDbuu2FhkGmUbYTCh3tzY' 'strict-dynamic'; style-src 'nonce-qdHVoB7kz1TPDbuu2FhkGmUbYTCh3tzY' a.disquscdn.com; child-src fusiontables.googleusercontent.com fusiontables.google.com www.google.com disqus.com www.youtube.com syndication.twitter.com platform.twitter.com; frame-src fusiontables.googleusercontent.com fusiontables.google.com www.google.com disqus.com www.youtube.com syndication.twitter.com platform.twitter.com; connect-src 'self' links.services.disqus.com; font-src cdnjs.cloudflare.com fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com; form-action 'self'; report-uri https://alessandroz.report-uri.io/r/default/csp/reportOnly";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header Referrer-Policy strict-origin;   
add_header Accept-Ranges bytes;

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_min_length 256;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;

root /usr/share/nginx/hipaa;

location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
location = /robots.txt {log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }   

index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name hipaa.example.com;



location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
    }

#location ~ (\.cgi|\.py|\.sh|\.pl|\.lua)$ {
    #gzip off;
#root /usr/share/nginx/tripwire;
    #autoindex on;
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    #nclude /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    #fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /usr/share/nginx/tripwire;
    #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/tripwire$fastcgi_script_name;
#}

location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
    }
    }

    }
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You simply define a separate server block for each subdomain and configure it however you like. If you want more help please edit your question to include your nginx.conf and any site configuration files. You can see how this is done on my Nginx tutorial, which has config files you can download : https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/

Comment: I'm sorry, but it didn't work. I had the same problem, i'll upload my configs soon.

Comment: This is a misconfiguration issue, we can probably help, but you need to give appropriate information. Please edit the labels on your config files, remove any default configurations that aren't in use. Also please add matching curl and access logs to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to specify `default_server` to the `listen` directive of the server you want to be the default one?

Comment: Hi, I just tried to specify it in the default.conf but that doesn't change nothing, it still displays only TLSv1.2 even if in the configure i set TLSv1.1 for the sub domain. The default.conf is not the problem, the problem are the sub domains!

Answer (score 0):

Whether [`ssl_protocols`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_protocols) can be overloaded [has been answered on the nginx ML](https://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2017-January/052802.html) (typographical errors corrected):

> You can't overload ssl_protocols because OpenSSL works this way: it selects the protocol used before SNI callback (and this behaviour looks more or less natural because the existence of SNI depends on the protocol used, and, for example, you can't enable SSLv3 in a SNI-based virtual host).

Thus, you should only define `ssl_protocols` once. If multiple occurrences are found, I guess the first encountered value (when used at run-time) will be chosen.